# node-config returns always default settings

Tags: node-config

I'm moving a node.js/express application to nest.js. 
The config of the app is handled with node-config (`default.js` and host specific js-files). 
I have copied the config files to the new application folder, imported the config module, and used some `config.get()` calls. The old application works perfect but with nest.js I get only the settings from default.js. Does anybody know why node-config is not working with nest.js?

```
// main.ts
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as config from "config";

async function bootstrap() {
    const port = Number.parseInt( config.get( "application.port" ), 10 );
    console.log( `Server listening on port: ${port}` );

    const app = await NestFactory.create( AppModule );
    await app.listen( port );
}
bootstrap();
```

config.get() returns always the value from default.js

Comment: You're gonna need to show some code and what's happening. It seems like `node-config` is expecting a `conf` directory at your project root.

Comment: Folder layout of the 2 applications is the same
/src/...
/config/...
The nest.js application seems to find the folder because it returns the default settings from default.js in the config folder.

Comment: [Is this the package you are using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-config)? Like I said, seeing some code and what's happening could be useful

Comment: Its this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/config the naming is a little bit strange sometimes with/without node.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `host specific js-files` and can't see anything immediately wrong with what you've shown. From looking at the `npm` package, it _looks_ like `config` changes what it pulls from based on `NODE_ENV` if you have things like `development.js` and `production.js`, but without seeing more, I couldn't say

Comment: If you put files with ```<hostname>.js``` in the config folder these will be used instead of the ```default.js```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, there must be some changes between versions 2 and 3 of the config module that made the filename loading algorithm case sensitive. Going back to v2 solved the problem. :-)